# 100% width doesn't work on a div. WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have set on my site a 100% width on a div. It doesn't work for that section. Please look at my site.

> http://patwoj.hekko24.pl/esportowy/

The nav on the top of the site with the games names **(black one)** should be 100% width.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `margin-left` to `padding-left` and add a `width` 100% in your `site-content` class.

```
.site-content {
    padding-left: 300px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%; 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I not clear with your problem but make sure The header is **not** inside the page div .Move the header outside of that div. and you need to manipulate your margin.

Answer (score 0):

Change this css. Remove `margin-left:300px` and use `width:100%` on `site-content` class.

```
.site-content {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in this page there are two main div's |
-Sidebar width 30%
-Content width 70%
And your menu is in Content div that's why menu 100% width means 70% width of Content div.You have to takeout menu div from Content Div and place it in start of Page div.